# Как выбрать несколько столбцов из массива в Matlab?

Tags: массивы, matlab

Я создаю массив MxN, необходимо выбрать несколько столбцов с конца массива, то есть несколько столбцов с номерами N, N-1, N-2...N-K, в Matlab. Поиск по документации ничего не дал.

Comment: ну это вроде как азы

Comment: @PavelGridin, вроде бы и азы, но как это сделать не вручную, если мне, допустим, нужно выбрать 3000 последних столбцов из массива с 10000 столбцов?

Comment: читать лень короче, если A этот массив, значит то что вам надо 
`A(:,end-3000:end)`

Comment: @PavelGridin, спасибо, это решило мою проблему